# On Hover for Kivy ActionBar ActionButton

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, kivy

According to [This Github File](https://github.com/kivy/kivy-designer/pull/172/files), I was trying to create a hover for an action button in python 3.7.5 windows 10 platform. This is what i tried:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.actionbar import *
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty
class HoverBehavior(object):

    hovered = BooleanProperty(False)
    border_point= ObjectProperty(None)
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.register_event_type('on_enter')
        self.register_event_type('on_leave')
        Window.bind(mouse_pos=self.on_mouse_pos)
        super(HoverBehavior, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def on_mouse_pos(self, *args):
        if not self.get_root_window():
            return # do proceed if I'm not displayed <=> If have no parent
        pos = args[1]
        #Next line to_widget allow to compensate for relative layout
        inside = self.collide_point(*self.to_widget(*pos))
        if self.hovered == inside:
            #We have already done what was needed
            return
        self.border_point = pos
        self.hovered = inside
        if inside:
            self.dispatch('on_enter')
        else:
            self.dispatch('on_leave')

    def on_enter(self):
        pass

    def on_leave(self):
        pass
from kivy.factory import Factory
Factory.register('HoverBehavior', HoverBehavior)
Builder.load_string("""
<TitleBar>:
    ActionBar:
        pos_hint: {'top':1}
        width: 50
        color: [ 1, 1, 1, 1]
        ActionView:
            use_separator: True
            ActionPrevious:
                title: 'Hello'
                with_previous: False
                color: [ 0, 0, 0, 1]
            ActionOverflow:
            ActionButton:
                icon: 'icons/app_close_init.png' if self.hovered else "icons/app_close_hover.png"
                on_press: app.closing()
            ActionButton:
                important: True
                text: 'Important'
                color: [ 0, 0, 0, 1]
            ActionButton:
                text: 'Btn2'
            ActionButton:
                text: 'Btn3'
            ActionButton:
                text: 'Btn4'
""")
class TitleBar(FloatLayout):
    pass

class TetraApp(App):

    def build(self):
        Window.size=(875,575)
        Window.clearcolor = (1, 1, 1, 1)
        Window.borderless=True
        return TitleBar()
    def on_press_button(self):
        return self.root.add_widget(Label(text='Hello'))
    def closing(self):
        app.stop()
if __name__=='__main__':
    app=TetraApp()
    app.run()
```

The Error says that Action Button has no attribute `hovered` but I have defined the `HoverBehaviour` class. What have I done Wrong? The action button is meant to change the icon image from one to another when the mouse hovers on it.
**EDITED**
Also tried:

```
class HoverBehavior(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.hovered = BooleanProperty(False)
        self.border_point= ObjectProperty(None)
        self.register_event_type('on_enter')
        self.register_event_type('on_leave')
        Window.bind(mouse_pos=self.on_mouse_pos)
        super(HoverBehavior, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def on_mouse_pos(self, *args):
        if not self.get_root_window():
```

But that too shows the `Attribute Error`.

Comment: You haven't defined the on_hover method right?
Maybe adding `def on_hover(self): pass` will make it work.

Comment: @SwastikUdupa it says`AttributeError: 'ActionButton' object has no attribute 'hovered'`

Comment: I tried defining `hovered` in class `TetraApp` and nope!

Comment: try using `self.hovered = BooleanProperty(False)` in the class when you instantiate hovered.

Comment: @SwastikUdupa in which class? could you tell the line?

Comment: class hoverbehaviour. Instead of line `hovered = BooleanProperty(False)`

Comment: @SwastikUdupa it says self not defined

Comment: You need to initialize the hovered and border_point variable with an init function like this


`def __init__(self):


  self.hovered = BooleanProperty(False)

  self.border_point= ObjectProperty(None)
`

Comment: nope! still there is the same attribute error

Comment: Even when you move  hovered = BooleanProperty(False)
    border_point= ObjectProperty(None) into the __init__ ?

Comment: ya. I ill update the Question with the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined your `HoverBehavior`, but you haven't actually used it, so the `ActionButton` knows nothing about `HoverBehavior`. To use it, define your own custom `ActionButton` like:

```
class MyActionButton(HoverBehavior, ActionButton):
    pass
```

Then, in your `kv` file, replace `ActionButton` with `MyActionButton`:

```
        MyActionButton:
            icon: 'icons/app_close_init.png' if self.hovered else "icons/app_close_hover.png"
            on_press: app.closing()
```

Comment: Perfect!. but why doesnt the `width:50` and `color: [1,1,1,1]` in actionbar work? It isint for me. I'm trying to get the action bar white and to change its size

Comment: To change its width, you must first turn off the `size_hint` for the width, Use `size_hint_x: None`. The background color of the `ActionBar` is actually an image. To eliminate the image, and get a white background, use `background_image: ''`.

Comment: Thank you ! you are brilliant But the background is still black

Comment: I had to change color to background color. thank you

Comment: The [Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) is good, but I learned by just programming in python and much time spent reading the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/) to figure out how to use specific parts of Python.

Comment: I saw an answer you said and i tried `canvas.before:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: 'icons/background.jpg'` but it says none type not subscriptable.